# How to format user input to allow xx.xx format

Tags: javascript

I have an input field that I want to format so it only allows currency but in a xx.xx or just xx format.

I do not want to allow

- $
- ,
- or a second '.'

So these examples would be acceptable

```
1 | 1.12 | 22.22 | 123 | 1234.44 | .55
```

But these would not be

```
$1, | 1.11.11 | .11.11 | , | 1,000
```

I've written this regex statement that I think does this

```
\d{0,}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

And I've written the javascript that I thought would give me the formatted value. But it throws an error

```
   $('#Overlay').on('keyup', '#Amount', function(event) {
       var val = $('#Amount').val();

        var replaceVal = this.value.replace(\d{0,}(\.\d{1,2}), '');
        if(this.value != replaceVal){
          this.value = replaceVal;
        }

   });
```

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.*

Just so it's clear, if a user types in an invalid character the code should fire and remove the problem. So if a user types **12.12.** it should append **12.12** to the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unexpected token is in

```
replace(\d{0,}(\.\d{1,2}), "")
```

regex starts with

```
/\d{0,}(\.\d{1,2})/g
```

you may want to try string.match(regexp) for your problem.
[JavaScript String match() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_match.asp)
If your text does not match just cut the last char of the string